# Commit made to Docker Image Not Working?

Tags: wordpress, docker

I'm new to Docker and tried pulling a Wordpress docker image, making some changes, committing it, and uploading the new image to docker cloud.

However when I restarted the docker image, I do not get back to the state that was committed earlier. Am I doing something wrong?

1. `docker pull tutum/wordpress:latest`
2. Setup Wordpress, add a theme, added pluigins, add some pages
3. `docker commit -m "First commit" <CONTAINER ID> foo/bar`
4. `docker login`
5. `docker push foo/bar:latest`
6. Restarted docker container. Back to where I was after doing `docker pull tutum/wordpress:latest`

Tried `docker pull foo/bar:latest` and was told `Image is up to date for foo/bar:latest`.

Comment: What changes are you trying to make?

Comment: @JHarris Uploaded a theme, added new pages. This docker image has mysql bundled in, so shouldnt committing the docker container also save the new data added to MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

You're not doing anything wrong! One of the core tenants of Docker is that containers are supposed to be immutable; that is, once you build a container, you should expect it's state to remain the same for the entirety of it's lifecycle. From the information that you provided, it looks like you started with Tutum's Wordpress file, https://github.com/tutumcloud/wordpress

This is going to be deprecated shortly, and you will have better luck using the officially supported wordpress docker image: https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/

If you're looking to hack on this on your local environment, and/or persist the changes to the docker image, you'll want to set something up like this (taken from one of our Dockerfiles):

```
FROM wordpress:latest

# installs php zip extensions - used for plugins like duplicator
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip 

# Copy the existing app into our wp directory

COPY . /var/www/html

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/

CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

If you would like to make changes to the image (e.g. setup plugins and themes), you'll want to create a mount point from your local computer into the docker container. To create a mount point, when you build your container, use the `-v` tag to set a volume.

An alternate approach to this is to use `docker-compose` (I recommend this, and we use it for our development in-house):

```
app:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - .:/var/www/html
  ports:
    - "80:80"
```

Save that as `docker-compose.yml`, and then you can run `docker-compose build` / `docker-compose up` to get your application off the ground.

Once you've made your changes (with the mount point in tact), you'll want to go ahead and tag this image. By tagging the image, you should be able to push it to your private docker hub registry, under your unique user.

This image will then contain all of your changes, since the changes that you make on your local environment will be copied directly into the image (note the `COPY` line).

Hope this helps!

-meoww-

Answer (score 0):

Containers are stateless, so restarting your Docker image essentially creates an new container instance of that image. Unless your Wordpress container persists its data in a [data volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/data-volumes), the changes that you made are gone after the current container is destroyed. Since that image's Dockerfile isn't published, it's hard to tell where its data is persisted. The other thing is the `docker commit` [command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) does not commit any data stored inside the container's volumes.

Take a look at [this Wordpress image](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/), it allows you to specify the MySQL container to link to for persistence.